# Bash Script - adduser

Tags: bash

Please help me. I wanted to write a script to add users. It was supposed to work in such a way that after creating one user, it asks whether to create another. I also wanted to display that the user was added or not added. The script I have works, but there is one problem. If I create a user by entering the correct password, I get a message that "user has been added". If I enter the wrong username, I get a message that "Failed to add a user "$username" !". However, when I create a user and enter two different passwords, I get an error that the passwords do not match. I abort adding the user and then the script says "user has been added". How do I fix this error, so that the script serves - if i cancel adding user it will show "error". Thanks for any tips.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while [ $count -le 10 ]
do
while true; do
read -p "Do you want to add a user ? (Y/n) " yn
case $yn in
[yY] ) read -p "Enter a username without sudo privileges : " username
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "User $username exists!"
else
adduser --gecos GECOS "$username"
usermod -aG sudo "$username"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "user has been added." || echo "Failed to add a user "$username" !"
fi
break;;
[nN] )  echo -----------------------------------------------;
count=$((10));
break;;
* ) echo invalid response;;
esac
done
count=$((count+1))
done
```

---

correct display of the script's operation

Update.
When I add the user correctly, I get the information -
user has been added.
when I enter the wrong name, I get the information -
Failed to add a user "$username" !
when I enter the wrong passwords and cancel adding a user, I get:
user has been added.

I tried to remove adding to the group, but the result is as above.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
read -p "Do you want to add a user ? (Y/n) " yn
case $yn in
[yY] ) read -p "Enter a username without sudo privileges : " username
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "User $username exists!"
else
adduser --gecos GECOS "$username"
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "user has been added." || echo "Failed to add a user "$username" !"
fi
break;;
[nN] )  echo -----------------------------------------------;
break;;
* ) echo invalid response;;
esac
done
```

Comment: its something about `useradd` or more likely `usermod`. Test those 2 together on the command line, forcing an error and then immediately do `echo $?`. You need to see a `1` returned for your `&&` and `||`rd logic to work. It looks like `usermod` is returning a 0 when it should return 1, but as I can't test in your environment, you'll have to dig in a little more. Did you serach here to see how accepted answers deal with `adduser && usermod`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried - adduser --gecos GECOS "$username" && usermod -aG sudo "$username" but when I cancel adding user it shows "user has been added.". I also removed usermod -aG sudo "$username" , and when I canceling adding a user it shows "user has been added." .

Comment: ??? Does this answer your orginal question or are you restating your prroblem? Assuming the later, you shold add this as a comment to your orginal question OR better yet, include it in the body of your question. Readers need code (and results) they can copy/paste in their environment and see the same results, hence my recoomendation to test on command line i.e. `adduser .... ; echo $?; usermod ... ; echo $?` Edit your Q to show the results of those operations. Good luck.

Comment: It was a comment :) .